# MVC, Razor, CSS and Dynamic Div ids

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm running into an issue with MVC the CSS for the objects and handling it it with the id's based on the name.

What i have is

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <div class="row d-flex">
            <div class="col my-0 my-md-5 position-relative category-container p-0 p-sm-3 d-inline-block">
                <div id^=@item.Description class="category mx-auto">
                    @Html.ActionLink(@item.Description], "LoadById", new { id = item.Id })

                </div>

             </div>
         </div>

    }
```

The CSS is set to reference the text the "id" should have, IE Desktops, Laptops, etc.
I've created a string[] and assigned it to the item.Description as well
then tried referencing  the string name a[0] in the css, but it doesn't see that either.
Is there a way to have the CSS find the ID variables to have the formatting handled properly?

the CSS I have/Tried is

```
 #dashboard #Desktops {
    background-image: url("../images/dashboardImages/real/desktops.jpg");
}
 #dashboard #a[0] {
    background-image: url("../images/dashboardImages/real/desktops.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Did you intend to have the "^" in <div id^= and the "]" in @Html.ActionLink(@item.Description] ?

Comment: yeah that was from something else I had tried, Selects all values that start the same way, to see if it could even find the value, but nope and i just left it in as while it didn't fix this particular issue, it didn't hurt anything either. It has since been removed

Answer (score 0):

Here's a template for you to work with, which I hope fits in from what you've described, which can be adjusted to what you specifically need.

ViewModels:

```
public class TestPageViewModel
{
    // Include a list (IEnumerable) of your item model
    public IEnumerable<TestItemViewModel> TestModelItems { get; set; }
}
public class TestItemViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Css { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

In Controller Action for View:

```
// Make the list of items (using a method of your choice)
var modelItems = new List<TestItemViewModel>
{
    new TestItemViewModel { Id = 1000, Css = "laptops", Description = "Laptops Category" },
    new TestItemViewModel { Id = 1001, Css = "desktops", Description = "Desktops Category" },
};
// Assign model items to the page View Model
var viewModel = new TestPageViewModel {
    TestModelItems = modelItems
};
```

In the View:

```
<div id="dashboard">
    @foreach (var item in Model.TestModelItems)
    {
        <div class="row d-flex">
            <div class="col my-0 my-md-5 position-relative category-container p-0 p-sm-3 d-inline-block">
                <!-- Reference the item.Css, item.Id or combinations of the two -->
                <div id="@item.Id" class="category mx-auto @item.Css @item.Css-@item.Id">
                    @Html.ActionLink(item.Description, "LoadById", new { id = item.Id })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Css Examples (adjust to taste):

```
#dashboard .laptops a{
    color: green;
}
#dashboard .desktops a{
    color: blue;
}
#dashboard .laptops-1000{
    background-color: yellow;
    padding:5px;
}
#dashboard .desktops-1001{
    background-color: cyan;
    padding:5px;
}
```